# How to pass a bitmap from C++ DLL to a VB6 app

Tags: c++, vb6

I have some C++ code that captures a raw image and builds a BMP which is saved to a file xyz.bmp. This works fine.

However the objective is to get that image data directly across to a VB6 app so no intermediary file is written out.

Searching around I can't really find much at all by way of an example or clear explanation and my C++ is sketchy at best.

C++ DLL code:

```cpp
extern "C"  _declspec(dllexport) HRESULT CaptureSample(BYTE *pbByteArray, int *pnSize)
{
....
....
    std::string bmpFile = "data/fingerPrint_" + s.str() + ".bmp";
    MessageBox(0, L"Saving", L"title", MB_OK);
    BmpSetImageData(&bmp, data, width, height);
    BmpSave(&bmp, bmpFile);

    const int nSizeOfData = sizeof(bmp);
    *pnSize = min(nSizeOfData, *pnSize);
    ::memcpy(pbByteArray, bmp, *pnSize);
```

In the above I have `pbByteArray` and `pnSize` to be returned to the VB6 app.

The function `BmpSave` works fine.
It is the next few lines of code I am coming unstuck on. `::memcpy .. bmp` is invalid - "no suitable conversion function from SBmpImage".

On the VB6 side:

```vb
Public Declare Function CaptureSample Lib "ImageLibrary.dll" (ByVal FScan As Byte, ByVal FScanSize As Integer) As Long

Private Sub Command_Click()
Dim FScan As Byte
Dim FScanSize As Integer

Call CaptureSample(FScan, FScanSize)
```

Again not sure of this is the correct approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So `bmp` is declared as `SBmpImage`, could we see the definition of that? Hard to answer the question without that important information. Also `sizeof(bmp)` is certainly wrong. You seem to think that it will give you the size of your image in bytes, but it won't. `sizeof` is a C++ language construct which has no knowledge of bitmaps.

Comment: `CaptureSample` must be declared as `(ByRef FScan As Byte, ByRef FScanSize As Long) As Long`, and you must pass an allocated buffer. You have to guess the size of the buffer though because the function will not tell you.